# Meaning of verb + の+ ではないかという

Tags: meaning, usage

How can I interpret this sentence:

> これから次第に広まって日常的に使うようになるのではないかという視点で選ばれるこのイベントは、

In this paragraph:

> ところで、みなさんは　“ほぼほぼ”という言葉を　聞いたことがありますか？ 実は、この言葉は、辞書で有名な三省堂が主催した今年の新語大賞に選ばれました。 新語として選ばれる基準は「その年を代表する言葉で、今後の辞書に掲載されてもおかしくないもの・今後定着しそうな言葉」なんだそうです。 流行語大賞とコンセプトは違って、耳に残るインパクトのある言葉ではありませんが、**これから次第に広まって日常的に使うようになるのではないかという視点で選ばれるこのイベントは、** 面白いと感じました。

The translation is:

> By the way, have you heard of the term 'hobo-hobo'? Actually, this word was chosen for this year's New Word Prize which is held by Sanseido, which is a firm famous for making dictionaries. The criteria needed in order to be chosen as the New Word is that it has to be “a word represents that particular year, it wouldn't seem out of place to publish the word into the dictionary from here on, and that it is word that will more than likely become a household word in time”. I felt that this event was interesting since the word is chosen from a different viewpoint than that of the concept of the buzzwords contest, in that it is not a word that stays on your mind or creates an impact, but one that will gradually spread and may become a word that gets used in everyday conversation.

I don't know how ではないかという fits in this sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not a fixed expression but just ではないか＋という which just happened to be next to each other. If we split them, the sentence could be parsed like this:

> これから次第に広まって日常的に使うようになるの**ではないか**
>
> From now on, [this word] **might** gradually spread and become used in everyday speech
>
> **という**視点で選ばれるこのイベントは
>
> an event of being chosen based on **such** a viewpoint
>
> 面白いと感じました。
>
> [I] felt that it was interesting

Comment: why was this answer down voted

Comment: yeah, I would appreciate a hint if I made a mistake somewhere.